# What is correct German word for "native land"?

Tags: translation, word-choice

I'm writing a book, and I made a rule for myself, to name every chapter in German (not that I knew German really well). So trying to name a chapter, I've found that in German there are several words, meaning homeland, motherland and so on. I'd like to know which of them is most close for country, where a country of origin, but not "motherland" in spiritual meaning of this word.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I support Ingmar's suggestion. Here's a list which I tried to order from - let's say - non-neutral to neutral.

1. ***Vaterland:*** may sound a bit lofty and/or patriotic
2. ***Heimatland:*** This also is usually considered the country of origin. Someone may, however, adopt a country as *Heimatland* where he's not born in, because he now considers it his (new) *Heimat*. Also ***Heimat*** alone is a wide term and can be used to denote the native land. There is e. g. an entire genre of movies named *Heimatfilm*.
3. ***Ursprungsland:*** This is literally *country of origin*.
4. ***Herkunftsland:*** Probably a bit more sober than *Ursprung*. *Ursprung* can have something profound in it.
5. ***Geburtsland:*** Well, it's the country you've been born in. It may have slightly technical connotation.

The latter three hardly have a particular connotation.

Comment: Well, in fact *Vaterland* even sounds etymologically *patriotic*, doesn't it? ;-)

Comment: Note that in 2. through 4. and maybe 5. one may substitute *land* by *staat* or other municipalities such as *stadt* and *ort*. *Urpsrung* is usually confined to a geographical and unmediated meaning, whereas *Herkunft* may relate more to ancestry. In certain contexts, but not here, *Nation* may also work.

Answer (score 3):

The most common choice is probably *Vaterland* although *Heimatland* might work as well.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what can easily be found in any dictionary. But as I said, I need the word which means "land of origin", and not "land I live and love". The question is more about right choice than translation itself.

Comment: I am afraid I really can't give you a different answer. By default, use _Vaterland_. You don't have to love it or identify much with it, it's still your fatherland.

Answer (score 3):

The terms of Ingmar are correct.

Alternatives: land of origin you can use [*Heimat*](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Heimat). See the translations to some languages in the link.

You also can use *Mutterland*, which bears a colonial connotation or means also land of origin as explained in this example:

> Das *Mutterland* des Taekwondo ist Korea